# Could not find tools.jar React native Android in Mac OSX

Tags: android, macos, react-native, java-home

I reach this step  :

```
reactive-native run-android ;
```

When I run `echo $JAVA_HOME`, i got the full path to JDK directory :

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

I add that path to `./android/gradle.properties` :

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/
```

I got the same error which is  :

> ..... .... :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Could not find tools.jar
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> .....

Answer (score 4):

**This error pops up, when some plugins of react-native like masked-view unable to locate tools.jar path in your machine which exists inside JDK home lib directory.**

With respect to this question, what you did is almost right but you added the Internet Plugins path which is incorrect. You have to add the jdk path of your machine.

**Locate JDK path :**

If your JAVA_HOME variable exists then you can find directly via terminal using
vim .zshrc or vim .bashrc command where must exists a path similar to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk{Your Machine JDK Version}/Contents/Home **(Copy this JAVA_HOME path)**

**After getting path of JDK, under android folder in gradle.properties file add this line**

```
org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk{"REPLACE_IT_WITH_YOUR_JDK_VERSION"}/Contents/Home
```

Hope this will help you or somebody else!

Thanks :)

Comment: This one works for me after I upgrade the minimum requirements to api 30

Comment: this one worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You should download JDK, finish the installation and add lib's path to PATH. In my case:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/lib
```

It's at the same level with bin, which is:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem. My java path was wrong.

Previously i was using '/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java'

I changed to '~/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java'

Now issue is solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install JDK and set the JAVA_HOME pointing to your installation, example:

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_311.jdk/Contents/Home

Then you need to set the Path to bin:

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

You can find more info on below link:
[https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0917/inst_jdk_javahome_t/index.html#:~:text=To%20set%20JAVA_HOME%2C%20do%20the,Program%20Files%5CJava%5Cjdk1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0917/inst_jdk_javahome_t/index.html#:%7E:text=To%20set%20JAVA_HOME%2C%20do%20the,Program%20Files%5CJava%5Cjdk1).